# Trocar a cor de parte do texto no input usando Vuejs/Html/css

Tags: html, css, vue.js, sass

Como por exemplo no Facebook quando digitamos *Parabéns fulano de tal* dentro do input a palavra parabéns fica negrito e laranja e a pessoa continua digitando normalmente... ou seja ... quando a pessoa digita o parabens preciso trocar somente essa palavra para outro estilo e o demais continua o estilo padrão.

Comment: Isso não é input. É algum tipo de div editável com várias funções atreladas.

Comment: Seria isto https://jsfiddle.net/valdeirpsr/36aeL6h0/ ? Você pode enviar o conteúdo da `div` para um `input:hidden`, dessa forma você poderá enviar o conteúdo através do `<form>`

Comment: é basicamente isso mesmo... obrigado